# Extract the body of email using Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I know that Azure Logic App enables us to extract email attachments. However, I also want to save the body of the email to perform information extraction in Azure. Is there any way to save emails in Azure Blob Storage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can fetch the email body in the create blob action like this.
[image]

Let me know if you are looking for something else.

Comment: This is great! Indeed this is what i am looking for. many thanks @Haris Abdulkareem